# modular use of a page on multiple domains

Tags: php, javascript

I am looking for the best way to do this.. basically i have multiple domains hosted on the same server. Each domain will have a page that is the same across them all. I want it to be modular in the sense that if i change it in one place it will be changed on all of them. What is the best way to do this? My site is built using PHP and Javascript, by the way.

Thanks

(my thought would be having the page listed on one main site and then have all others 'include' it? )

Thanks

Comment: Same content (even with different stylesheet) on multiple domains = [duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359). You probably want to avoid it.

Comment: the different domains are due to different markets(locations) but the sites will have the same structure

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well you want to have n domain names redirecting to the same code base you duplicate.

If that is the case then the best way to handle this is to use virtual host.
In apache it would like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example1.com
  ServerAlias www.example1.com
  ServerAlias example2.com
  ServerAlias www.example2.com
  ApplicationRoot /home/myWebSite
</VirtualHost>
```

What this does is creating an Apache virtual host which deliver the code contained at `/home/myWebSite` for all the DNS given as `ServerAlias` and the `ServerName`.

This is by far the cleanest way to do it, by doing this each DNS will be preserved in the url, no redirections.

Comment: what exactly does this do? for example i have a template, but on each domain it loads different data to in, and has a different style sheet, is my goal

Comment: @TroyCosentino I added some explanations.

Comment: that makes sense, this would make them all identical though, correct? would there still be a way to have certain files unique to the different domains?

Comment: Nop. With this would get the EXACT same website, with just a different DNS in the URL. But you can in PHP use `$SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` do figure out which DNS you are on.

Comment: @3on,.. I suppose one could use multiple folders to design the different CSS for other domains all on the one server and just reference that folder? I have yet to learn XML; only php SQL at this point. Is XML able to provide more fields from db than simple title description? I know XML is supposed to allow you your own tags so technically one could build multiple sites based on one db. Accessing db from another server is bad news! :) Sorry I am so green, but this question is exactly what I was going to ask. Very curious. Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with XML, this is an Apache configuration file which ad a syntax sort of XML but whatever. So the initial question was how to serve the EXACT same website if you want to have the same backend but different static files (CSS; JS etc..) It would be a different problem, which could be solve with rewrite rules for example.